# Rename a submodule in a module in python

Tags: python, module

I am reading a python code and meet a code like this.

```
import mod1 as m

# ...

do_something(m.sub_a) #1
```

However in `m`, `sub_a` is missing, but `sub_aa` exists. How can I make change in the code to rename `sub_a` into `sub_aa` without changing the code in `#1`? Like,

```
import mod1 as m

import mod1.sub_aa as mod1.sub_a # do something like this

do_something(m.sub_a)
```

p.s. As `sub_a` has been used in many files, and `mod1` is not suggest to modify, I have to write some wrapper to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import mod1.sub_aa as mod1.sub_a` is a syntax error, because you can only have a simple name on the right side of `as`, not a name inside a module.

You can use assignment to create a new name inside the module instead:

```
m.sub_a = m.sub_aa
```

Comment: For a strange kind of fashion, this answer seems to be better than mine. +1

Comment: Does it also work if `sub_aa` is a module? Sorry, I do not have a python prompt to test it right now.

Comment: @Xiaolong: Yes it will. If you can access the module as `m.sub_aa` then this will allow you to access it as `m.sub_a` as well.

Comment: @NlightNFotis Yes. Python is flexible, and I really like it. Thank you very much :)